# Ansible copy module ignores role files directory

Tags: ansible

I'm having the following issue and am not sure if it's a bug or my setup is wrong. I've created a role `ssh` with the following structure:

```
.
├── roles
    ├── ssh
    │   ├── files
    │   │   └── sshd_config
    │   └── tasks
    │       └── main.yml
```

The main.yml file looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: "Set sshd configuration"
      copy:
        src: sshd_config
        dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Because `sshd_config` is stored in the recommended `files` directory, I expected the `copy` command to automatically fetch that file when referencing it from the task.
Instead, Ansible looks for `sshd_config` in the following directories:

```
ansible.errors.AnsibleFileNotFound: Could not find or access 'sshd_config'
Searched in:
    <redacted>/roles/ssh/tasks/files/sshd_config
    <redacted>/roles/ssh/tasks/sshd_config
    <redacted>/roles/ssh/tasks/files/sshd_config
    <redacted>/roles/ssh/tasks/sshd_config on the Ansible
```

Notice it does look in a `files` directory, but does so in the `tasks` folder!

Main goal is to send a local file (on my host machine) to the remote server.

I run the playbook with following command:

`ansible-playbook -i hosts ./roles/ssh/tasks/main.yml -vvv`

Questions:

1. Is my assumption right Ansible should look for the file in the `files` directory adjacent to `tasks` directory?
2. Did I mess up my setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you confused [roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html) with [playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks.html). You created a playbook in place where the role should be. You rather should create a role and then create a playbook (outside of `/roles` dir) that uses it.

Here's example `/roles/ssh/tasks/main.yml`:

```
- name: "Set sshd configuration"
  copy:
    src: sshd_config
    dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and playbook using `ssh` role:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
   - import_role:
        name: ssh
```

Comment: That's exactly what happened, and got it working as expected right now. Thank you!